# How do I switch the values of three variables in python?

Tags: python

I was studying python and one of the questions on my test was:

> What is the output of the following piece of code?
>
> ```
> x=1
> y=2
> x, y, z = x, x, y
> z, y, z = x, y, z
> print(x,y,z)
> ```

The answer was `1,1,2`, but I don't understand how `z = 2`. Here's how I've done it:

```
x,y,z = x,x,y => x = x = 1
                 y = x = 1
                 z = y = 2 

z,y,z = x,y,z => z = x = 1 
                 y = y = 1
                 z = z = 1
```

Comment: In the second tuple assignment you're setting `z` to `x` (1) and to `z` (2). The setting to 2 is the last, so `z` ends up set to 2.

Comment: I think you need to understand that each time you assign variables it overwrites. So on your final explanation where you said "z = z = 1" that's not true, because previously z was overwritten to be the value of "y" which was "2"

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, you can also see [this video (at the provided  timestamp)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=2041s) from an excellent talk by a member of the Python dev team.

Comment: I don't understand what the title of this question has to do with the question being asked. What do you mean by "switch the values of three variables"? It doesn't seem as if you're *trying* to write code that, given existing `x`, `y` *and `z`* values, produces different values according to a rule. It seems as if you're trying to understand the behaviour of someone else's code. That's a different question.

Answer (score 3):

It evaluates the right hand side first ... so Z is still 2

```
z,y,z = x,y,z =>  x,y,z = 1 ,1 ,2 # evaluates RH side first
```

and as mentioned below

```
z,z = 10,20

# z is 20
```

Comment: And the lhs from left to right, which means the second rebind of `z` "wins".